# How to add a system service to Cloud Foundry step by step

Tags: cloud-foundry

I want to add new system service to micro cloud. and following the steps specified in docuement "How to add a system service to Cloud Foundry step by step" for adding echo service.
But i don't see the specified folder structure in my system where i have my micro cloud.
Thanks
Saidesh

Answer (score 5):

The docs are in the source tree on CloudFoundry.org.  For doing development work, that's where the best information is.  Here's the doc that I used: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/oss-docs/tree/master/vcap/adding_a_system_service

One other thought tho:  If you're wanting to add a "service", then I'd suggest not using Micro Cloud Foundry, but instead setting up a Ubuntu virtual machine and installing the code base from CloudFoundry.org.  Instructions for doing so can be found here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/oss-docs/tree/master/vcap/single_and_multi_node_deployments_with_dev_setup

Hope that helps,
John